# Check if a field is typing.Optional

Tags: python, python-3.7, typing

What is the best way to check if a field from a class is typing.Optional?

Example code:

```
from typing import Optional
import re
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TestClass:
    required_field_1: str
    required_field_2: int
    optional_field: Optional[str]

def get_all_optional_fields(fields) -> list:
    return [field.name for field in fields if __is_optional_field(field)]

def __is_optional_field(field) -> bool:
    regex = '^typing.Union\[.*, NoneType\]$'
    return re.match(regex, str(field.type)) is not None

print(get_all_optional_fields(fields(TestClass)))
```

Where `fields` is from `dataclasses`, I wanna list all the `Optional` fields.
What I'm doing at this moment to solve it, is using a Regex-based on the field name, but I don't like this approach. Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: what's `fields` declaration and expected output?

Comment: Fields extract information for a given type without the need of creating an object.

Comment: then post it. perhaps, it could be optimized

Comment: Updated with more info now

Comment: Updated the post with a working code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Optional[X]` is equivalent to `Union[X, None]`. So you could do,

```
import re
from typing import Optional

from dataclasses import dataclass, fields


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class TestClass:
    required_field_1: str
    required_field_2: int
    optional_field: Optional[str]


def get_optional_fields(klass):
    class_fields = fields(klass)
    for field in class_fields:
        if (
            hasattr(field.type, "__args__")
            and len(field.type.__args__) == 2
            and field.type.__args__[-1] is type(None)
        ):
            # Check if exactly two arguments exists and one of them are None type
            yield field.name


print(list(get_optional_fields(TestClass)))
```

Comment: It won't work on every python3 version. My library has checks https://github.com/ltworf/typedload/blob/master/typedload/typechecks.py#L105 https://github.com/ltworf/typedload/blob/master/typedload/typechecks.py#L200

Answer (score 27):

For reference, Python 3.8 (first released October 2019) added `get_origin` and `get_args` functions to the `typing` module.

Examples from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_origin):

```
assert get_origin(Dict[str, int]) is dict
assert get_args(Dict[int, str]) == (int, str)

assert get_origin(Union[int, str]) is Union
assert get_args(Union[int, str]) == (int, str)
```

This will allow:

```
def is_optional(field):
    return typing.get_origin(field) is Union and \
           type(None) in typing.get_args(field)
```

For older Pythons, here is some compatibility code:

```py
# Python >= 3.8
try:
    from typing import Literal, get_args, get_origin
# Compatibility
except ImportError:
    get_args = lambda t: getattr(t, '__args__', ()) \
                         if t is not Generic else Generic
    get_origin = lambda t: getattr(t, '__origin__', None)
```

Comment: FYI you can import `get_args` and `get_origin` from [typing-extensions](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) for Python 3.7+

Comment: looks like this is not working if new Union notation is used, i.e. str|None.

Answer (score 10):

Note: `typing.Optional[x]` is an alias for `typing.Union[x, None]`

Now, one could inspect the attributes of your input field annotation to check if it is defined like Union[x, None]: 
You can read its attributes `__module__`, `__args__` and `__origin__`:

```py
from typing import *

def print_meta_info(x):
      print(x.__module__, x.__args__, x.__origin__)

x = Optional[int]
print_meta_info(x) # 'typing', (class Int,), typing.Union

x = Union[int, float]
print_meta_info(x) # 'typing', (class int, class float), typing.Union

x = Iterable[str]
print_meta_info(x) # 'typing', (class int,), typing.Iterable
```

You need to take this steps to define your checker:

1. Make sure that the annotation has the keys `__module__`, `__args__` and `__origin__`
2. `__module__` must be set to 'typing'. If not, the annotation is not an object defined by the typing module
3. `__origin__` value is equal to typing.Union
4. `__args__` must be a tuple with 2 items where the second one is the class NoneType (`type(None)`)

If all conditions are evaluated to true, you have typing.Optional[x] 
 
You may also need to know what is the optional class in the annotation:

```py
x = Optional[int].__args__[0]
print(x) # class int
```

Answer (score 5):

Another approach (That works on both python 3.7 & and 3.8) is to relay on how the set `Union` operation works:

`union([x,y],[y])= union([x],[y]) = union(union([x],[y]),[x,y])`

The logic is that `Optional` type can't be `Optional`er. While you can't directly know if a `type` is nullable/optional, `Optional[type]` would be the same as `type` is the `type` is optional and other (`Union[type,None]` to be exact) otherwise.

So, in our case:

```py
Union[SomeType,None] == Union[Union[SomeType,None]]
```

(the first is eqivalent to `Optional[SomeType]` and the second to `Optional[Optional[SomeType]]`

This allows very easy check for `Optional` values:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields
from typing import Optional


@dataclass()
class DC:
    x: Optional[str] = None
    y: str = "s"


def get_optional_fields(cls):
    fields_list = fields(cls)
    return [
        field.name 
        for field in fields_list if 
        field.type == Optional[field.type]
    ]



if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_optional_fields(DC())) # ['x']
```

Comment: Nifty. I think typing should override `__eq__` shuch that `Optional[T] == Union[T, None]`.

Comment: Sweet. Love your answer!

Answer (score 3):

Python 3.10 adds the notation `T | None` to specify a union type (see [PEP 604](https://peps.python.org/pep-0604/)). In my local Python 3.10.7, `types.get_origin` converts this to `types.UnionType` (not `typing.Union). So the following works for flat unions (but see SimSimY's answer regarding nested unions).

```
import typing
import types

def field_is_optional(cls: type, field_name: str):
    """A field is optional when it has Union type with a NoneType alternative.
    Note that Optional[] is a special form which is converted to a Union with a NoneType option
    """
    field_type = typing.get_type_hints(cls).get(field_name, None)
    origin = typing.get_origin(field_type)
    #print(field_name, ":", field_type, origin)
    if origin is typing.Union:
        return type(None) in typing.get_args(field_type)
    if origin is types.UnionType:
        return type(None) in typing.get_args(field_type)
    return False
```

and here is a test:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Optional, Union

@dataclass
class A:
    foo : Optional[int] = None
    bar : int|None = None
    baz : Union[int, float, None] = None
    x : int = 1

a=A()
assert field_is_optional(type(a), "foo")
assert field_is_optional(type(a), "bar")
assert field_is_optional(type(a), "baz")
assert field_is_optional(type(a), "x") == False
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called typedload which can be used to do this.

The main purpose of the library is conversion to/from json and namedtuple/dataclass/attrs, but since it needed to do those checks, it exposes the functions.

Note that different versions of python change how the internal typing API works, so checks will not work on every python version.

My library addresses it internally, hiding the details to the user.

Using it, the code is like this

```
from typing import *
a = Optional[int]

from typedload import typechecks
typechecks.is_union(a) and type(None) in typechecks.uniontypes(a)
```

https://github.com/ltworf/typedload

Of course, if you don't need to support multiple python versions, you might not care to depend on a library just for this, but future releases might break the check. They have changed API even between minor releases.